# link_to xml request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here's my current hack:

```
<%= link_to "Retrieve as XML", products_path + ".xml" %>
```

...which works just fine, but is obviously quite ugly.

What is the proper way?

I searched [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html) for an answer - no luck.  Some old forum posts suggest there is (or was) a `format` option, but it seems this is no longer available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<%= link_to "Retrieve as XML", products_path(:format => 'xml') %>
```